# Reorder an element in an ordered list with a single update

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting

Say I have a list that is order by a `priority` property of its elements, which is a number. I know the `priority` value of every member of the list, but I want to move one element to a specific index. Is it possible to do so by only modifying the `priority` of the element I want to move?

The `priority` doesn't need to be a whole number. Any algorithm can be used to determine what the `priority` of the element needs to be, but the `priority` must be unique.

I would think get the `priority` of the elements before and after the desired index, but I don't know how to pick a number between them that won't eventually result in a duplicate. If I just add some given value (whole or decimal) to the element before, I will eventually get the same value as the element after. Calling `random()` with a range between the two would work, but that seems like a *really* roundabout way of doing things.

If this kind of operation has a name, I am also interested in learning it.

Comment: Why do you pick a priority *between* those other priorities? Priorities don't have to be unique, right?

Comment: So basically you are having issues with colliding priorities. What does that mean to your program (when priorities collide)?

Comment: @delnan - "but the priority must be unique"

Comment: What about (upper+lower)/2 ?

Comment: isn't the order of the elements the real priority? the actual index?

Comment: @MatthewRapati They will be persisted in a db, and read out. I need a real value to represent their order, not the index of the array in memory.

Comment: Are the priorities contiguous?

Comment: @TravisJ They don't need to be

Comment: @TravisJ If priorities collide, then the sort won't be deterministic.

Comment: @msander I think that works... that was devilishly simple wasn't it? I feel a bit slow now.

Comment: If you are interested in theoretical background, have a look at the chapter "Numbering schemes" here: http://www.cs.uni-paderborn.de/fachgebiete/ag-boettcher/lehre/ss2012/dbis-2/download.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A value m = (upper+lower)/2 is always in the middle of two values.

For further reading on numbering I refer to a lecture:
http://www.cs.uni-paderborn.de/fachgebiete/ag-boettcher/lehre/ss2012/dbis-2/download.html

Comment: I assume you mean `upper + lower / 2`. Then it should be said that this scheme results in a duplicate priority after about S iterations (`m = (m + upper) / 2`) where S is the bit size of the significant of the float format. For 64 bit floats ("double") S = 52, which is not a whole lot of insertions.

Answer (score 1):

> What about (upper+lower)/2 ?

Expanding a bit on @msander's answer, you could use an alpha-numeric priority to make sure you always have "middle" priority to assign. If you need to assign many priorities, the distance between two consecutive priorities will get lower and lower and eventually it will lose precision and you will have something like ((upper + lower)/2 === lower).

Instead of actual numbers you could use strings (no loss of precision) if you change how you get the middle priority. For example if your priorities are string-like numbers (strings composed of 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9):

['1', '3', '4']

Moving 4 between 1 and 3 will result in :
['1', '2', '3']

Moving 3 between 2 and 1 will result in :
['1', '15', '2']

Moving 2 between 1 and 15 will result in :
['1', '12', '15']

All you need to take care is how you compare the priorities (String.prototype.localeCompare).

Again, this solution is only worth the trouble if you expect to run into trouble with precision loss.

**EDIT (added a function that computes the priority):**

Disclaimer: The code is unexpectedly difficult to follow. If anyone has a better idea, feel free to chip in. If you only use binary strings (strings containing only 0 and 1), it will be much easier to write.

```
function getMiddlePriority(p1, p2) {
  var i=0,result = '';

  // The identical digits need to be in the result
  while ((p1[i] || '0') === (p2[i] || '0')) {
    result += p1[i++] || '0';
  }

  // First different digit p1[i] !== p2[i]

  // if the digits are far enough apart, there is a number between them
  if ((p2[i]||0) - (p1[i]||0) > 1) {
    return result + Math.floor(((+p2[i]||0) + (+p1[i]||0))/2);
  }

  // p2[i] === p1[i]+1

  // Digits are close, need to parse some more digits to get a number between
  var first = i++;
  var k = 0;
  while ((p1[i] === '9') && ((p2[i]||'0') === '0')) {
    i++; 
    k++;
  }


  // p[i] is not 9 or p2[i] is not 0/undefined
  if (p1[i] === '9') {
    result += (p2[first]||'0')  + repeat('0', k);
    result += p2[i] === '1' ? '05' : Math.floor(p2[i]/2);
  } else {
    result += (p1[first]||'0') + repeat('9', k);
    result += Math.floor((10 + (+p1[i] || 0))/2);
  } 

  return result;
}


function repeat(character, count) {
  var s = '';
  while (count--) s+= character;
  return s;
}


console.clear();
console.log('Expected 2 Got ' + getMiddlePriority('1', '3'));
console.log('Expected 25 Got ' + getMiddlePriority('2', '3'));
console.log('Expected 22 Got ' + getMiddlePriority('2', '25'));
console.log('Expected 21 Got ' + getMiddlePriority('2', '22'));
console.log('Expected 205 Got ' + getMiddlePriority('2', '21'));
console.log('Expected 202 Got ' + getMiddlePriority('2', '205'));
console.log('Expected 215 Got ' + getMiddlePriority('21', '22'));
console.log('Expected 1055 Got ' + getMiddlePriority('105', '106'));
console.log('Expected 10995 Got ' + getMiddlePriority('1099', '11'));
console.log('Expected 1105 Got ' + getMiddlePriority('1099', '111'));
```

---

An alternative to string priorities is to use digit priorities and every once in a while (when `(upper+lower)/2 === lower || (upper+lower)/2 === upper`) redistribute the priorities around. Of course this doesn't fit the question, because for N reorderings you will not do 1 update, but `1+ N/S` updates where S is the amount of updates you can do before you run out of available priorities. At least it is a correct solution (priorities will always be unique).

Comment: What kind of step are you using to pick the middle number? Your examples look like division, but your third is dropping precision. Isn't this going to run into the same problem?

Comment: The `(upper+lower)/2` solution can actually be any number between upper and lower. Half is good because it makes the average distance as large as possible, but any number is acceptable. The problem with JS numbers (double precision floating points) is that there is a finite number of them. Using the string method above, you can add as many characters as you want and you will never run out, you never run the risk of having `a === a+1`. I will edit my answer with a function that computes the average priority for the string example above.